# Using onblur, texture saves to db without website template but doesn't with

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, onblur

I am using onblur in a textarea to save to db. The textarea is embedded in a table, within a template site. If I copy the code onto a blank page the onblur function works a dream, but put within the layout it doesn't.

Any help much appreciated!!

```
<td class="text-center">
        <textarea onblur="myFunction(this)" textarea name="notepad" id="notepad" data-id="notepad"><?php
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM *** WHERE `***` = '".$_SESSION['***']."'");

                    $stmt->execute();
            
                    $result = $stmt;
            
                    foreach($result as $row) {
                        echo $row['evidence'];
                    }
        ?></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction(elm){
        console.log('textare blur'+elm.value);
         var notepadVal = elm.value; 
        var id = elm.id; 

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "***.php",
             data: {notepad:notepadVal,id:id},
             success: function(msg) {
                // $('#notepad-' + id).val(msg);
             }
       });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</td>
```

Comment: Firstly, please indent your code properly. It makes it so much easier to read. Are you putting the script tags in the table? I don't think that's a good idea. You could try putting them at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @leighboz thanks for the suggestion but hasn't worked.

Comment: If you put `console.log('myfunction()');` as the first line of the function, does it log? Is the function being called?